Is it not recommended to use unprivileged users to insmod drivers in Linux?
Background:

Unprivileged users can use CAP_SYS_MODULE capability to insert module to kernel.
Insmod a ko include load driver and driver init.

My issue:
My test driver will crate debugfs at init_module(), It return error when insmod the KO with unprivileged user.
int init_module(void) {
  static struct dentry *root_dir;
  root_dir = debugfs_create_dir("test", 0);
  if (IS_ERR_OR_NULL(root_dir)) {
    printk(KERN_ERR DEVICE_NAME " Failed to create root debugfs directory! \n");
  }
}

dmesg log:
[11830.033006][ T7727] test_device Failed to create root debugfs directory!

Inital Analysis:
The mode of /sys/kernel/debug is "0700", DAC check will return fail.
/* the trace of debugfs_create_dir() */
debugfs_create_dir()
start_creating()
    lookup_one_len()
        lookup_one_common()
            inode_permission()
                do_inode_permission()
                    generic_permission() {
                        if (S_ISDIR(inode->i_mode)) {
                            /* DACs are overridable for directories */
                            if (!(mask & MAY_WRITE))
                                if (capable_wrt_inode_uidgid(mnt_userns, inode,
                                    CAP_DAC_READ_SEARCH))
                                    return 0;
                                if (capable_wrt_inode_uidgid(mnt_userns, inode,
                                    CAP_DAC_OVERRIDE))
                                    return 0;
                                return -EACCES;
                            }
                        }

My question
CAP_SYS_MODULE is just a fine-grained privilege for insert ko to kernel space, Driver initialization may require other privileges that need to be specified additionally.
BUT, There are no unified rules describing the permission rules for kernel code. This is not like the API provided to userspace.
Does the kernel need to give clear advice that kernel modules cannot be loaded by unprivileged users?

This surprises me!  Perhaps it is a quirk of the debugfs functions, that they check permissions?
It doesn't look like procfs does.
I suspect sysfs is ok too - and that it is trivial for you to test - because every module load creates a directory under /sys/module/.
Another reason why debugfs might be unusual is:

NOTE: it's expected that most callers should ignore the errors returned by this function.  Other debugfs functions handle the fact that the "dentry" passed to them could be an error and they don't crash in that case.  Drivers should generally work fine even if debugfs fails to init anyway.

So perhaps most modules do not really notice if you load them like this and they fail to create their debugfs files?
Aside from debugfs, I imagine most module init functions do not manipulate files, processes etc using functions that are subject to permission checks?  I think some use request_module()... but they may get away with that because we already know they have CAP_SYS_MODULE :-).
(superuser might be the wrong place for this question :-).

My customer requires that all drivers on the platform be loaded for non-privileged users.  The drivers on the platform are complex and I cannot handle all potential risks. -- Nichel

In "standard" Linux, you can see modules are loaded by root - e.g. see systemd-modules-load.service and systemd-udevd.service. In fact, see the reference to CAP_SYS_MODULE in systemd-modules-load.service : the service is skipped if it is run inside a Linux container where this capability has been disabled.
I am not familiar with any system that uses CAP_SYS_MODULE like the test in your question.  If you don't have a working open-source example you could look at - I think it would be fair to say this is expensively untested territory :-).

Thank you sourcejedi.  The driver encounters very few permission checks. Currently, it only encounters the case of debugfs. I test /dev /sys /proc create no error.
NOTE for debugfs_create_dir，I think it has nothing to do with the permissions issue, it should be from a functionality perspective and its error can be ignored.
My customer requires that all drivers on the platform be loaded for non-privileged users. The drivers on the platform are complex and I cannot handle all potential risks.
I hope to get a unified answer from the principle analysis. "You must be root to load the driver".

Thanks for sharing your discoveries :-). I think I understand. I have extended my answer.
